# Extract multiple match values without duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, multiple-matches

I have a set of matching values as shown:
[image]

The input is a table with Order number in the first column and dates in the seventh column.

I would like to extract all the matching dates from the seventh column and display only the 'unique dates' in the columns against each matching order value.
If there are no matching values in the input, it should return blank values in output.

I use Excel 2016. The inputs are in sheet 2.

I managed to get the dates with array index formula but it is slow with large data.

Comment: When you say "table", do you mean a listObject? Or just a range in a sheet?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the new array functions `UNIQUE` & `FILTER` then:

---

Using the sample data below

1. In cell E1: `=UNIQUE(A1:A10)`
2. In cell F1: `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:B10,A1:A10=E1)))`
3. Then drag the formula from `F1` down to the last cell which will populate your desired table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next VBA solution. It should be very fast, using two dictionaries and arrays, mostly working in memory. It will return the processed result starting from "J2" cell. It can return anywhere, you should only change "J2" cell with the cell range you need, even being in another sheet:

```
Sub extractUniqueValues_Dat()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrIt, arrFin, Z As Long
   Dim dict As Object, dictI As Object, i As Long, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   
   arr = sh.Range("A2:G" & lastR).value             'place the range to be processed in an array, for faster iteration
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  'set first necessary dictionary
   
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate between the array rows and load the dictionary:
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then                     'if the key does not exist:
            Set dictI = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")   'set a new dictionary
            dictI.Add arr(i, 7), vbNullString                  'create a key of the new dictionary using first Date occurrence
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), dictI                          'create a dictionary key as Value and add the new dictionary as item
            If dictI.count > Z Then Z = dictI.count            'extract maximum number of Date occurrences
        Else
           dict(arr(i, 1))(arr(i, 7)) = vbNullString           'if the key of the item dictionary does not exist it is added, with an empty item
           If dict(arr(i, 1)).count > Z Then Z = dict(arr(i, 1)).count 'extract maximum number of Date occurrences
        End If
   Next i
   ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count, 1 To Z + 1) '+ 1, to make place for the dictionary key (in first column)
   
   'fill the arrFin array:
   For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
        arrFin(i + 1, 1) = dict.Keys()(i)                        'place the main dictionary key in the first column of the final array
        For k = 1 To dict.Items()(i).count
            arrFin(i + 1, 1 + k) = dict.Items()(i).Keys()(k - 1) 'place each date (extracted from the item dictionary keys) in the following columns
        Next k
   Next i
   
   'build the header:
   Dim arrH: arrH = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:" & Z & "))")
   arrH = Split("Match Value|Data " & Join(arrH, "|Data "), "|")
   
   'drop the final aray content and apply a little formatting:
   With sh.Range("J2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2))
        .value = arrFin
        With .rows(1).Offset(-1)
            .value = arrH
            .Font.Bold = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
   End With
   
   MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Please send some feedback after testing it.

**Edited**:

Please, test the next version. It will work even if the customer orders will not be unique (in K:K column)... This code will also extract only unique values from the mentioned range. It will also check if there are values in the processed sheet which cannot be found in K:K, and returns in the sheet being processed, starting from "M1". Please, **use the real sheet where K:K necessary column exists, when set `shK` sheet**!

```
Private Sub extractUniqueValues_Dat()
   Dim shK As Worksheet, lastRK As Long, sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrK, arrIt, arrFin, Z As Long
   Dim dict As Object, dictI As Object, dictK As Object, i As Long, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in B:B
   arr = sh.Range("B2:H" & lastR).Value                   'place the range to be processed in an array, for faster iteration
   
   Set shK = Worksheets("sheet KK")  'use here the necessary sheet (with values in K:K)!!!
   lastRK = shK.Range("K" & shK.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in K:K
   arrK = shK.Range("K2:K" & lastRK).Value
   
   Set dictK = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  'set first necessary dictionary
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")    'set first necessary dictionary
   
   'place the UNIQUE values in a dictionary, as keys and all unique date, for all accurrences in an item array:
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate between the array rows and load the dictionary:
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then                                    'if the key does not exist:
            Set dictI = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")   'set a new dictionary
            dictI.Add arr(i, 7), vbNullString                                'create a key of the new dictionary using first Date occurrence
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), dictI                                               'create a dictionary key as Value and add the new dictionary as item
            If dictI.count > Z Then Z = dictI.count                            'extract maximum number of Date occurrences
        Else
           dict(arr(i, 1))(arr(i, 7)) = vbNullString                       'if the key of the item dictinary does not exist it is added, with an empty item
           If dict(arr(i, 1)).count > Z Then Z = dict(arr(i, 1)).count 'extract maximum number of Date occurrences
        End If
   Next i
   
   'place the UNIQUE vales from K:K column, only as keys:
   For i = 1 To UBound(arrK)
        dictK(arrK(i, 1)) = vbNullString
   Next i
   
   ReDim arrFin(1 To dictK.count, 1 To Z + 3) '+ 1, to make splace for the dictionary key (in first column)
   
   'fill the arrFin array:
   For i = 0 To dictK.count - 1
        arrFin(i + 1, 1) = dictK.Keys()(i)                 'place the main dictionary keyi in the first column of the final array
        If dict.Exists(dictK.Keys()(i)) Then
            For k = 1 To dict(dictK.Keys()(i)).count
                arrFin(i + 1, 3 + k) = dict(dictK.Keys()(i)).Keys()(k - 1) 'place each date (extracted from the item dictionary keys) in the following columns
            Next k
        End If
   Next i
   
   'check if there are missing values from sheet with processed data:
   Dim arrMiss, KK As Long, boolMiss As Boolean
   ReDim arrMiss(dict.count)
   For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
        If Not dictK.Exists(dict.Keys()(i)) Then
            arrMiss(KK) = dict.Keys()(i): KK = KK + 1
        End If
   Next i
   
   'build the header:
   Dim arrH: arrH = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:" & Z & "))")
   arrH = Split("Match Value|x|y|Data " & Join(arrH, "|Data "), "|")
   
   'drop the final aray content and apply a little formatting:
   With sh.Range("M2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2))
        .CurrentRegion.Value = "" 'if the previous return dropped more rows than the actual one...
        .Value = arrFin
        With .rows(1).Offset(-1)
            .Value = arrH
            .Font.Bold = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
   End With
   If KK > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arrMiss(KK - 1)
        MsgBox "Missing Values: " & vbCrLf & Join(arrMiss, vbCrLf), vbInformation, "Please, check..."
        boolMiss = True
   End If
   If Not boolMiss Then MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Send some feedback after testing it, please...

Comment: It worked well. Maybe I didn't make it clear the first time. The match value in the output is hard coded and can be any order no. Some of those order nos may not be present in the input list. Then there shouldn't be any dates for that order no. Can you tweak the code to do that.

Comment: @kapib I am afraid I cannot get you... What does "order no" mean? Are they data in the `Value` column? If so, what do you want saying? Is it possible to such values exist, let us say, "12345_14" which does not have any date in column "G:G"? **If so**, did you test the above code for such a case? It will return only the value ("order no") without any Date. Do you want something else? **If not** please, better explain what you want.

Comment: I need dates corresponding to matching values (order no). If a value is not present in the input it should return blank instead of dates, in the output. I have edited the original post and added a new image to make it clear.

Comment: @kapib Do you really understand what you ask for? My above code does **exactly what you say in your last comment**. Your last 'updated' image only confuses me. Do you understand that, so named, output **is only the result of input processing, as you required**? Do you want saying **now** that in the output part **there are already UNIQUE order no.** and the processing result should be placed on the existing lines?  If so, you did not mention that even if the updated question. I only can deduce that looking to the (strange) picture...

Comment: @kapib Since you asked about an issue, can you clarify my above clarification questions? I can do it in any way, but **you need to clearly describe what you really want/need**. And do that in terms I tried specifically asking, especially **are there already UNIQUE order no. in the Output part/table (etc.)"...

Comment: ok. I will try to explain it better. I have Sheet 1 with a set of values (in my case customer order) in Column K. In sheet 2 I have a table (ref picture) with lots of duplicate customer orders and corresponding dates. I need to extract all the matching, unique dates and display horizontally against each cust order in sheet 1.The current code considers only the cust orders from the input table. I am basically looking for an advanced VLOOKUP which returns multiple, unique dates corresponding to each cust order I give. If the cust order I give in Column K is not present in Column B, return blank

Comment: @kapib I am afraid I am still not sure I understood  what you try explaining. I specifically asked about the unicity of **the other orders no you were talking about in your comment**. Let me try explaining what I think it is clear and asking about what is not: 1. In the "Sheet2" there are all data which my above code already processes. Is this understanding correct? 2. In the other sheet (sheet 1 you say) there are **customer orders"** in column "K:K". I suppose that these "customer orders" are the one found in B:B column of "Sheet 2". Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @kapib Now, you did not clarify a question I asked it twice, even emphasized it writing UNIQUE in Upper case... So, **are these customer orders from sheet 1, UNIQUE**? 3. **Where do you like the code to return the processed result**, independent of the answers/confirmations of the previous issue?

Comment: ok. so the cust WO in column K is what I enter manually. It can be anything. I don't want the code to extract cust WO from input. I want the code to extract only the matching dates from input. it should return only the dates (unique) against each matching cust WO (which I enter manually in Column K). If the cust WO I enter in Column K is not present in Column B, the code should return blank against those cust orders. When I run the code, I want it to populate only matching dates, from Column N onwards. I hope I made it clear this time. :-)

Comment: @kapib I cannot understand what you mean and I am tempted to abandon any attempt. Did you test the last code I posted? It does exactly what you say: "**it should return only the dates (unique) against each matching cust WO (which I enter manually in Column K)**"! I do not know what is to be done if you do not clearly explain **what it should do AGAINST WHAT IT ALREADY DOES**.